# Django:What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, django, forms

These are my models:

```
class war(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class option(models.Model):
    warval =models.ForeignKey(war)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class warform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = war

class option_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = option
    exclude = ('warval')
```

And this is the view which handles creation of option:

```
def warhandler(request,war_id):
    f=modelformset_factory(option,form=option_form)
    wobj=get_object_or_404(war,pk=war_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = f(request.POST,queryset=option.objects.filter(warval=wobj))
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponse("Saved!check your model")   
        else:
            return render_to_response("formset.html",RequestContext(request,{"set":formset}))
    else:
        formset = f(queryset=option.objects.filter(warval=wobj))
        print(formset)
        return render_to_response("formset.html",RequestContext(request,{"set":formset,"war":wobj}))
```

So when I submit the form to this view,I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: hit_option.warval_id may not be NULL
```

I know what this error is and why it is coming but how can I remove this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make warval a non-required field with

```
class option(models.Model):
    warval =models.ForeignKey(war, null=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

or define formset.warval before saving,  make a default value...

**edit:**

read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) for using subset of fields on a form and saving.

Comment: Can you tell me how and where to define "formset.warval"?

Answer (score 2):

As you realize, this is because you're not setting the foreign key value anywhere. You probably want to use [`inlineformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) which will take care of setting the FK to the parent `war` object for you.

Comment: Inline formset is a good option.I tried it just now and the code worked great.But what if I had "User" foreign key too in "option" model?